# React useRef combined with useEffect not rendering initial values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render a list of values from an array, which can then be filtered to display search results. The code looks like this:

```js
 const { contacts, filteredContacts } = contactContext;
 const contactsRef = useRef(contacts);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (filteredContacts !== null) {
      contactsRef.current.value = filteredContacts;
    } else {
      contactsRef.current.value = contacts;
    }
  }, [filteredContacts]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {contactsRef.current.value &&
        contactsRef.current.value.map(contact => (
          <ContactItem key={contact.id} contact={contact}></ContactItem>
        ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
```

*Current behaviour* The list is that the list is only rendered if I type something in the search box - thus update filteredContacts value, and not on the initial render.

*Expected behaviour* The `contactsRef` should be initialised with the `.current.value` properties and rendered when the component has been loaded.

I am new to react, so please be kind :)

Comment: Did you try logging ```contacts``` to make sure it exists with the desired data inside your ```useEffect```?

Comment: filteredContacts is of type?...

Comment: you don't see the correct value because doing `contactsRef.current.value = ...` doesn't trigger a re-render of your component, actually you don't need to use a reference because you just want to display the `filteredContacts` or the `contacts` when  `filteredContacts` is not defined

Comment: As Olivier and Amit (accepted answer bellow) point out, useEffect does not trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you are trying to map over cotactsRef.current.value which is undefined because contactsRef.current has contacts not in value.

And you shouldn't use ref with useEffect because setting value in ref won't trigger re-render. Just use variable to render from which contacts.

```
 const { contacts, filteredContacts } = contactContext;
 const displayContacts = filteredContacts || contacts;

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {displayContacts && displayContacts.map(contact => (
          <ContactItem key={contact.id} contact={contact}></ContactItem>
        ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: This works! I was assuming that the ui would always reflect the `current` value of the reference, without having to re-render the whole component. Thanks!